# ForLoop/Array Issue

Tags: java, arrays

I am having a little trouble figuring out what to do when it comes down to this project (generally the same for all my projects). I just want to know if I'm headed in the right direction also, I am not sure how to store the float number in the int double array. Thanks

**Question & SampleOutput**

Write a Java program that prompts the user to enter an integer. Use the integer as the  size for a new double array. Use a ​for loop to prompt the user to enter a floating point number for each element in the 
array, and store the number in the array.  Use a  second ​for loop to, calculate the average of all of the numbers and print it.

Your  output should look something like the following:

> How many numbers will you enter: 5
>
> Enter a decimal value: 21.2
>
> Enter a decimal value: 3.7
>
> Enter a decimal value: 10.5
>
> Enter a decimal value: 2.6
>
> Enter a decimal value: 101.123
>
> The average is 27.824599999999997

---

My current code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Loops {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print(" How many numbers will you enter: ");
int numberOfTimes = input.nextInt();


int[][] Array = new int[numberOfTimes][];

for(int i = 0; i < Array.length; i--)
{
    System.out.print("Enter a decimal value: ");
    float value = input.nextInt();
    Array[i][
    
    
    
    {
        
    }
}

}
}
```

PS: My apologies for bad formatting. New to Stack.

Comment: You cannot store `float` values in an `int` array. Why can't you use a float array instead?

Comment: This code won't even compile.  Please tidy it up if possible.

Comment: The directions actually say *Use the integer as the  size for a new **`double` array**.*

Comment: the **double** in the directions is for the datatype and you need to use a single-dimensional array

Comment: Java variable names should be camelCase unless its a final constant. Even if you want to use CapitalCase for your variables don't use names like `Array` as there are already library classes with that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sir,

The major mistake you're committing is considering double as two. 'Double' is also a data type just like integers and float. So you need only a one dimensional array to store the values which are of type 'double'.

Secondly, i would suggest you to try to completing the code yourself once. If you're having issues in compiling it or getting wrong output, feel free to post the code online.

The desired result could have been achieved with only one 'for' loop, but I've provided the code 2 'for' loops only for the clarity.

Here's the code-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AverageNumber {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("How many numbers will you enter: ");
int numberOfTimes = input.nextInt();

double AverageMean = 0;
double[] Array = new double[numberOfTimes];

// Doing the first loop as suggested
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++)
{
    System.out.print("Enter a decimal value: ");
    Array[i]  = input.nextDouble();
}

// Doing the second loop as suggested
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++)
{
    AverageMean = AverageMean + Array[i];
}

System.out.println("The average is " + AverageMean/5);

}

}
```

And the desired output will be-

```
How many numbers will you enter: 5
Enter a decimal value: 21.2
Enter a decimal value: 3.7
Enter a decimal value: 10.5
Enter a decimal value: 2.6
Enter a decimal value: 101.123
The average is 27.824599999999997
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print(" How many numbers will you enter: ");
    int numberOfTimes = input.nextInt();


    float[] input = new int[numberOfTimes];

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter a decimal value: ");
        float value = input.nextInt();
        Array[i] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You need a `double` array instead of a two dimensional `int` array to store `double`.

2) Use `input.nextDouble();` to take a `double` input.

3) `for(int i = 0; i < Array.length; i--)` will cause `i` to decrease negative which will next create `ArrayIndexOutofBound` exception at `Array[i]`.

4) There are some other errors, better try the following code.

Try this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Loops {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(" How many numbers will you enter: ");
        int numberOfTimes = input.nextInt();

        double[] Array = new double[numberOfTimes];
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a decimal value: ");
            double value = input.nextDouble();
            Array[i] = value;
            sum += value;
        }
        average = sum / numberOfTimes;
        System.out.print("The average is: " + average);
    }
}
```

Output:

> How many numbers will you enter: 5
>
> Enter a decimal value: 21.7
>
> Enter a decimal value: 3.7
>
> Enter a decimal value: 10.5
>
> Enter a decimal value: 2.6
>
> Enter a decimal value: 101.123
>
> The average is: 27.924599999999998